# Mean and variance of a moving normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, estimation

For a static normal distribution with fixed parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, the [sample mean and sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters) can be used to estimate $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$, maybe additionally using a [trimmed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimmed_estimator) or [winsored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorising) estimator.

What is the case when both $\mu(t)$ and $\sigma^2(t)$ are a (continuous) function of the time $t$? Is there any way to update the estimates based on previous values?

An example might be market [bids and asks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bid%E2%80%93ask_spread), where several people state their buying price for an item (say, a stock, or apples). Over time, the price may move higher or lower, but it can be frequently sampled to observe even small changes.

Comment: Can you say something about what these functions might look like?  The case where $\sigma^2(t) = \sigma^2$ for instance is addressed by standard regression techniques.

Comment: @dsaxton: They can be sampled often enough that you can observe small movements. (But without them being continuous, it might be impossible).

Comment: One possibility might be to estimate the functions with splines, perhaps using some sort of weighting of the residuals to account for heteroskedasticity of the error term.  You could first fit the function $\hat{\mu}(t)$ and then fit another model to the squared errors $(\hat{\mu}(t) - y(t))^2$, although some care would have to be taken to avoid overfitting (i.e., underestimation of $\sigma^2(t)$).  Are you able to provide a sample of your data and / or a scatter plot?

Comment: @dsaxton: Would you still like some sample data even though there are already answers, or not?

Comment: No, it seems other users are figuring it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mean and variance can be updated incrementally.

The details are in the seminal book

> Donald E. Knuth (1998).
>  **The Art of Computer Programming, volume 2: Seminumerical Algorithms**

Comment: Searching 'knuth art of computer programming update mean and variance' points to Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance. That references volume two of "The Art of Computer Programming".

Comment: [A blog](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/standard_deviation/) gives a reference of "Donald Knuth’s Art of Computer Programming, Vol 2, page 232, 3rd edition"

Answer (score 1):

[@Anony-Mousse's post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/201519/95892) gave some terms to google, which led to [this dsp.SX question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/811/determining-the-mean-and-standard-deviation-in-real-time/1599#1599). There are two approaches, one of which is the Knuth  from the other answer. [The other](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/892/16927)

> weighs more recent samples stronger than samples from the distant past.

The update algorithm (slightly edited) is given as

> ```
> % update the estimate of the mean and the mean square:
> mean = (1-a)*mean + a*x
> meansq = (1-b)*meansq + b*(x^2)
>
> % calculate the estimate of the variance:
> var = meansq - mean^2;
>
> % and, if you want standard deviation:
> std = sqrt(var);
> ```

The choice of `a` and `b` determines how strongly to weigh the newer values. [The dsp.sx question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/811/determining-the-mean-and-standard-deviation-in-real-time/1599#1599) has answers which partly contain how to determine it.